# Связный список на С++, проблема с созданием элемента

Tags: c++, список

Пишу небольшую базу данных. В структуру входит фамилия студента и 3 оценки. Все это нужно запихнуть в односвязный линейный список и работать с ним дальше. Когда хочу создать любой элемент списка, компилятор выдает: "Выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением". В чем проблема?
Код:

```
struct students
{
    char surname[20];
    int marks[3];
} onestudent;

struct studentlist
{
    students a;
    studentlist *next;
};

void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    studentlist *u = NULL;  //указатель на начало списка
    u = new studentlist;

    u->a.surname = scanf("%s", onestudent.surname);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        u->a.marks = scanf("%d", onestudent.marks[i]);
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Нет в C никакого `new`!

Comment: @Pink Tux да, в си malloc, но с нас преподаватель требует именно new.

Comment: Значит, уточните у преподавателя что он имеет в виду. Или речь всё-таки идёт о C+++, или вы его не так поняли. Больше тут помочь нечем. Кроме как `void * new(size_t size) { return malloc(size); }`...

Comment: Проблема тут: `scanf("%s", onestudent.surname)`. `onestudent.surname` - вообще непонятно что такое. Должно быть `scanf("%s", &(u->a.surname))`

Answer (score 4):

Ну вот, раз уж C++, то не используйте `scanf` (тем более - неправильно). В C++ для этих целей есть `std::cin`:

```
studentlist *u = new studentlist;
u->next = NULL;

std::cin >> u->a.surname;

for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
    std::cin >> u->a.marks[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

scanf возвращает количество элементов - т.е. int. А Вы пытаетесь этот int присвоить массивам.